# Web Audio API glitching/distortions issues

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm new to the web audio API and made a simple synthesizer to learn the ins and outs.  Trouble is my audio distorts quite a bit after heavy sound input.  So if I push a ton of frequencies through it will distort. Could anyone knowledgeable about the API take a quick peek at my code to see if any major mistakes/omissions stick out?  Can recreate issue in Safari, chrome, and Firefox.  Demo version is [HERE](https://fedreg.github.io/Web-Audio-API-Synth/) Thanks for any help!!

```
//start new audio session.
var context = new (window.webkitAudioContext || window.AudioContext || window.mozAudioContext)



function playSound(note) {
    oscillator = context.createOscillator();

//create volume controller
var gainNode = context.createGain();

//connect signal to audio output(speakers by default)
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(context.destination);

//adjusts frequency played by 50%, 100% or 200% 
var octave = document.getElementById('octave').value;

//sets oscillator frequency
oscillator.frequency.value = frequencies[note] * octave;

//oscillator wave type
oscillator.type = document.getElementById('waveSelect').value;


//initialize gain at 0 and ramp up to full volume very quikcly (prevents audible 'pop')
gainNode.gain.value = 0
var quickFadeIn = gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.1);

//starts oscillator. Delayed start can be achieved by adding time(in secs) after currentTime
oscillator.start(context.currentTime + .05);

/**
 *  AUDIO EFFECTS
 */

function delayNode() {
    //create delay
    var delay = context.createDelay();
    delay.delayTime.value = .5;

    //create gain
    gainNode;
    //gainNode.gain.value = 0.8;
    quickFadeIn;

    //create feedback loop
    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(delay);
    delay.connect(gainNode);
    delay.connect(context.destination); 

    //decrease gain
    quickFadeOut;
}

function distortionNode() {
    var distortion = context.createWaveShaper();

//distortion curve taken from MDN which they in turn took from Stack Overflow
    function makeDistortionCurve(amount) {
      var k = typeof amount === 'number' ? amount : 50,
        n_samples = 44100,
        curve = new Float32Array(n_samples),
        deg = Math.PI / 90,
        i = 0,
        x;
      for ( ; i < n_samples; ++i ) {
        x = i * 2 / n_samples - 1;
        curve[i] = ( 3 + k ) * x * 20 * deg / ( Math.PI + k * Math.abs(x) );
      }
      return curve;
    };

    distortion.curve = makeDistortionCurve(500);
    distortion.oversample = '4x';

    gainNode;

    quickFadeIn;

    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(distortion);
    distortion.connect(context.destination);

    //decrease gain
    quickFadeOut;   
}

if (document.getElementById('toggleDelay').value == 'true'){delayNode();}   
if (document.getElementById('toggleDistortion').value == 'true'){distortionNode();}

//determines note duration
var sustain = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sustain').value);

//stops oscillator by exponentially ramping down sound over .015 seconds to avoid audible click
var quickFadeOut = gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + sustain, 0.0015);

//change key color on keypress

    //append the word "note" to the object.name note to identify the correct key div
    var divId = "note" + String(note);
    var element = document.getElementById(divId);

    //change background color for durarion of note length
    var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor = '#3cf7ac';
    setTimeout(function () {
    if (currentColor != 'rgb(60, 247, 172)') {
        element.style.backgroundColor = currentColor
    }
 }, 1000 * sustain);



//for testing
console.log('playSound Hz:' + frequencies[note] * octave + ' octave:' + octave + ' wave:' + oscillator.type + ' duration: ' + sustain + ' time:' + context.currentTime.toFixed(2));
}

 //controls 2nd keyboard.  Same logic as playSound()
function playSoundb(note) {
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
var gainNode = context.createGain();
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(context.destination);



var octaveb = document.getElementById('octaveb').value;
    oscillator.frequency.value = frequencies[note] * octaveb;


oscillator.type = document.getElementById('waveSelectb').value;

gainNode.gain.value = 0
var quickFadeIn = gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(.75, context.currentTime, .1);
oscillator.start(context.currentTime + .05);

/**
 *  AUDIO EFFECTS
 */

function delayNode() {
    var delay = context.createDelay();
    delay.delayTime.value = .5;

    gainNode;
    quickFadeIn;

    //create feedback loop
    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(delay);
    delay.connect(gainNode);
    delay.connect(context.destination); 

    //decrease gain
    quickFadeOut;
}

function distortionNode() {
    var distortion = context.createWaveShaper();

    function makeDistortionCurve(amount) {
      var k = typeof amount === 'number' ? amount : 50,
        n_samples = 44100,
        curve = new Float32Array(n_samples),
        deg = Math.PI / 90,
        i = 0,
        x;
      for ( ; i < n_samples; ++i ) {
        x = i * 2 / n_samples - 1;
        curve[i] = ( 3 + k ) * x * 20 * deg / ( Math.PI + k * Math.abs(x) );
      }
      return curve;
    };

    distortion.curve = makeDistortionCurve(900);
    distortion.oversample = '4x';

    gainNode;
    quickFadeIn;

    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(distortion);
    distortion.connect(context.destination);

    quickFadeOut;
}

if (document.getElementById('toggleDelayb').value == 'true'){delayNode();}
if (document.getElementById('toggleDistortionb').value == 'true'){distortionNode();}        

var sustainb = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sustainb').value);

var quickFadeOut = gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + sustainb, 0.0015);

//change key color on keypress
var divId = "note" + String(note) + "b";
var element = document.getElementById(divId);
var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
element.style.backgroundColor = '#3ce4f7';
setTimeout(function () {
    if (currentColor != 'rgb(60, 228, 247)') {
        element.style.backgroundColor = currentColor
    }
 }, 1000 * sustainb);

//for testing
console.log('playSound*B* Hz:' + frequencies[note] * octave + ' octave:' + octave + ' wave:' + oscillator.type + ' duration: ' + sustain + ' time:' + context.currentTime);
```

}

```
//reveals 2nd keyboard
function displayKeyboard2(lowersynth, uppersynth) {
    var bottom = document.getElementById(lowersynth);
    var top = document.getElementById(uppersynth);

if (bottom.style.display == 'block') {
    bottom.style.display = 'none';
    top.style.marginTop = '150px';  
}

else {
    bottom.style.display = 'block';
    top.style.marginTop = '0';
}
```

}

```
//Frequencies in Hz of notes to be played. 
var frequencies = {
    'C_1': 130.81,
    'C#1': 139.00,
    'D_1': 146.83,
    'D#1': 156.00,
    'E_1': 164.81,
    'F_1': 174.61,
    'F#1': 185.00,
    'G_1': 196.00,
    'G#1': 208.00,
    'A_1': 220.00,
    'A#1': 233.00,
    'B_1': 246.94,
    'C_2': 261.63,
    'C#2': 277.00,
    'D_2': 293.66,
    'D#2': 311.00,
    'E_2': 329.63,
    'F_2': 349.23,
    'F#2': 370.00,
    'G_2': 392.00,
    'G#2': 415.00,
    'A_2': 440.00,
    'A#2': 466.00,
    'B_2': 493.88,
    'C_3': 523.25,
 };

 //triggers playSound() to create note
document.getElementById('noteC_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('C_1');});
document.getElementById('noteC#1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('C#1');});
document.getElementById('noteD_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('D_1');});
document.getElementById('noteD#1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('D#1');});
document.getElementById('noteE_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('E_1');});
document.getElementById('noteF_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('F_1');});
document.getElementById('noteF#1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('F#1');});
document.getElementById('noteG_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('G_1');});
document.getElementById('noteG#1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('G#1');});
document.getElementById('noteA_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('A_1');});
document.getElementById('noteA#1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('A#1');});
document.getElementById('noteB_1').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('B_1');});
document.getElementById('noteC_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('C_2');});
document.getElementById('noteC#2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('C#2');});
document.getElementById('noteD_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('D_2');});
document.getElementById('noteD#2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('D#2');});
document.getElementById('noteE_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('E_2');});
document.getElementById('noteF_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('F_2');});
document.getElementById('noteF#2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('F#2');});
document.getElementById('noteG_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('G_2');});
document.getElementById('noteG#2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('G#2');});
document.getElementById('noteA_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('A_2');});
document.getElementById('noteA#2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('A#2');});
document.getElementById('noteB_2').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('B_2');});
document.getElementById('noteC_3').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSound('C_3');});


document.getElementById('noteC_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('C_1');});
document.getElementById('noteC#1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('C#1');});
document.getElementById('noteD_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('D_1');});
document.getElementById('noteD#1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('D#1');});
document.getElementById('noteE_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('E_1');});
document.getElementById('noteF_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('F_1');});
document.getElementById('noteF#1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('F#1');});
document.getElementById('noteG_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('G_1');});
document.getElementById('noteG#1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('G#1');});
document.getElementById('noteA_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('A_1');});
document.getElementById('noteA#1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('A#1');});
document.getElementById('noteB_1b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('B_1');});
document.getElementById('noteC_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('C_2');});
document.getElementById('noteC#2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('C#2');});
document.getElementById('noteD_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('D_2');});
document.getElementById('noteD#2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('D#2');});
document.getElementById('noteE_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('E_2');});
document.getElementById('noteF_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('F_2');});
document.getElementById('noteF#2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('F#2');});
document.getElementById('noteG_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('G_2');});
document.getElementById('noteG#2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('G#2');});
document.getElementById('noteA_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('A_2');});
document.getElementById('noteA#2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('A#2');});
document.getElementById('noteB_2b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('B_2');});
document.getElementById('noteC_3b').addEventListener(('click' || 'touchstart'),function() { playSoundb('C_3');});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No major omissions - this is just what happens in digital audio when you overload the output (i.e. the instantaneous value of the audio is <-1 or >+1) - you get clipping, which is usually sounds pretty nasty.  Probably the best thing to do (other than keeping gain values lower than 1) is to put a DynamicsCompressor on the output (i.e. create a DynamicsCompressorNode via context.createDynamicsCompressor(), connect it to context.destination, then connect notes to the compressor rather than the context.destination).  The default values are reasonable to help in this kind of situation (compressor settings are a musical decision, but this will at least help with the clipping).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'll play around with the gain and compressor suggestions.  Good to know that I didn't make any major mistakes.  I really appreciate you taking a look at my code!!

Comment: woohoo man - this was spot on (!) Thanks.